# Desktop application development with offline maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, bing-maps, arcgis, offline-caching, openmap

I'm currently developing an application in which I need to use offline maps to put some markers, info, and geolocalization on it. It will be a web-based application, but I've seen that Google Maps API doesn't allow us to use maps offline because that will violate their TOS.

As a complement, my development team is willing to pay in order to get the maps we need, since we expect to have some support and reliability from the maps.

Therefore we were wondering which  Map service could we use to develop the application with offline maps, where I can move, zoom and interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Windows 10, there Bing Maps is built into the Windows 10 SDK and supports offline maps, geocoding and routing. You can find some documentation on this API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642089.aspx

Bing Maps does provide generous free limits for Windows based apps. If your app is public facing, you have a limit of 50,000 transactions a day. If your app is internal business facing, the limit is 125,000 transactions a year. Generally you will generate one transaction each time the map control is loaded.